# elasticsearch-hadoop for Spark. Send documents from a RDD in different index (by day)

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I work on a complex workflow using Spark (parsing, cleaning, Machine Learning ...).
At the end of the workflow I want to send aggregated results to elasticsearch so my portal could query data.
There will be two types of processing: streaming and the possibility to relaunch workflow on all available data.

Right now I use elasticsearch-hadoop and particularly the spark part to send document to elasticsearch with the saveJsonToEs(myindex/mytype) method.
The target is to have an index by day using the proper template that we built.
AFAIK you could not add consideration of a feature in a document to send it to the proper index in elasticsearch-hadoop.

What is the proper way to implement this feature? 
Have a special step using spark and bulk so that each executor send documents to the proper index considering the feature of each line?
Is there something that I missed in elasticsearch-hadoop?

I tried to send JSON to _bulk using saveJsonToEs("_bulk") but the pattern has to follow index/type

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'd love to know what the answer is. I've been working with Spark and ES (and blogging about it: http://blog.qbox.io/deploy-elasticsearch-and-apache-spark-to-the-cloud). I've had a pretty hard time finding adequate documentation and/or examples, particularly for using PySpark with Elasticsearch.

Comment: What I implemented is a specific spark job to send docs to Spark. I use foreachPartitions and instantiate a connection to Elasticsearch using transport client and a bulk processor. I'm not sure that it's the most effective way to do that but I have the possibility to consider a feature in rows to send data to the appropriate index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Costin Leau, I have the solution.
Simply use dynamic indexing with something like saveJsonToEs("my-index-{date}/my-type"). "date" have to be a feature in the document that has to be send.

Discussion on elasticsearch google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/5-LwjQxVlhk

Documentation: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-write-dyn

Comment: I am also trying to do something very similar to what you have done
in my json i have a filed "ts" value for this timestamp field is in Unix epoch ,i want index name to be like myindex-{date} how can i format this date into something like ts:yyy.mm.dd so that i have my index name as myindex-2015-09-30

Answer (score 0):

You can use : ("custom-index-{date}/customtype") to create dynamic index. This could be any field in given rdd.

If you want format the date : ("custom-index-{date:{YYYY.mm.dd}}/customtype")
[Answered to question ask by Amit_Hora in the comment, as I don't have enough privilege to comment, I am adding this here]